# SQL Azure installation issue

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

I have some problems related to installing SQL Azure tools through the web installer.
When it finished, it shows a list of tools that are not installed. When doing the coding, it is not showing all the options that should be there.

I am following the Windows Azure tutorial [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/tutorials/web-app-with-sql-azure/).

Regards
A.Samad

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is what instalator said after it finished. Which tools was not instaled?

When I instaled Azure the instalator showed that it encountered problems with activating IIS features (HTTP Rediction, Logging Tools, Tracing, CGI). I had to activate those manualy prior to azure instalation. After that everything went fine. 
Maybe you face this same issue.